# Can you help me to show datagridview and Refresh after update?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagridview

This is my code and error message when you running say:

> An unhandled exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

on this `da.fill(dt);`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANTONIANGGA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FullandStarving;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

public FormProduksi()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   showgridview();     
}

private void showgridview()
{
    con.Open();
    dt.Clear();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Produksi", con);
    //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; done :D
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Datetimepicker to Database
    string dProduksi = DateTime.Parse(dtmProduksi.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try{
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Produksi (IDProduksi,IDPhoto,TanggalProduksi,NamaKaryawan,KeteranganPhoto) Values('" + txtIdpro.Text + "','" + txtIdPhoto.Text + "','" + dProduksi + "','" + txtNamaKaryawan.Text + "','" + rxtKtrphoto.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Update telah di jalankan");
        showgridview();
        clear();
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image: is done now]

[image: The update successfully]

that update successfully but cant refresh, so i do quit that form and open can see it
[image: Update]

Comment: You are closeing connection and then after calling function. When you select query to required connection to open...

Comment: so what i should do ?
where i put code 'con.Open();' and 'con.Close()' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `showgridview()` function as below where **connection is opened & closed properly.**

Also check your sql query ,**provide space and maintain syntax of query** :

```
SELECT * FROM Produksi
```

Error screenshot clearly depicts that stored procedure with such name don't exist
[image]

**comment out those lines as code below** :

```
void showgridview()
{
    con.Open();
    dt.Clear();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Produksi", con);
    //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

Then you wont be having connection issues and errors related .

Button Click code **change the closing connection** as below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Datetimepicker to Database
    string dProduksi = DateTime.Parse(dtmProduksi.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Produksi (IDProduksi,IDPhoto,TanggalProduksi,NamaKaryawan,KeteranganPhoto) Values('" + txtIdpro.Text + "','" + txtIdPhoto.Text + "','" + dProduksi + "','" + txtNamaKaryawan.Text + "','" + rxtKtrphoto.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Update telah di jalankan");
        con.Close();
        showgridview();
        clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Also, for further reading:

[parameterized queries vs. SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection)

[Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Answer (score 3):

You are closing the connection

```
con.Close();
```

and then using

```
da.Fill(dt);
```

Just swap this lines:

```
showgridview();
con.Close();
```

For example with [`DbDataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

**Notes:**

## 1

Yoy should use parametrized queries so you avoid [SQL Injection attacks](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp):

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
```

## 2

Wrap `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using` so any resources used by those would [disposed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string position;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=free-pc\\FATMAH; Integrated Security=True; database=Workflow; "))
{
  con.Open();

  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @id", con))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);

    var name = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (name != null)
    {
       position = name.ToString();
       Response.Write("User Registration successful");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Employee found.");
    }
  }
}
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389906/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-occurred-in)